# How can I fetch cats from cataas.com API in python?

Tags: python-3.7

I want to fetch a list cats based on a search input entered, I am not sure of the end point to use . I want something like this [here](https://cataas.com/#/cats/tags/j/page/1)

I have tried to make a request to the API using requests API but I am not getting the desired results. Here is the code below

```py
import requests

def get_cats():
   response = requests.get('https://cataas.com/#/')
   print(response.json())

get_cats()
```

I am not getting any json format of cats but just an error:

```
"C:\Users\Developer\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).
```

Answer (score 1):

OK so after a real struggle I found a good endpoint that returns json and I got the code working. You can actually check it on my repo [django cataas app](https://github.com/Mathewsmusukuma/django-cataas-app)

The endpoint is `https://cataas.com/api/cats`

A little documentation is as follows:

```
/api/cats => get all cats

/api/cats?tags=cute => get all cats with cute tag

/api/cats?tags=cute,gif => get all cats with cute tag OR gif tag

/api/cats?limit=10 => get last 10 cats

/api/cats?limit=10&skip=10 => get last 10 cats after skip 10 of them

/api/cats?limit=6&tags=cute => get last 6 cats with cute tag`
```